# Arithmetic operations on Date values in Oracle

Tags: oracle, math, time, plsql

I am struggling with some case...

there is table, in which I have employee attendance records, for example:

for `empID=1`;

```
empID   time     Type   date
-------------------------------
1       9:22     in     sameday
1       11:23    out    sameday
1       14:35    in     sameday
1       16:21    out    sameday
```

particularly, I want some fn/procedure that will take an `EmpID` and `DATE` parameters, and then based on this data if I'll write: `select proc(EmployeeID, Date) from dual(or maybe some other table?)` it should do such a work:

take first couples in table (table is ordered be ascending as default order), then calculate FROM first OUT (11:23) to first IN(9:22) time, save that time somewhere (int tempResult) and then calculate second couple, and calculate second tempResult and in finalResult, it should count the total time, like `finalResult+=finalResult+tempResult` (if it has been an iterations in loop);

I think it would be done someway like, in foreach (or whatever it is in pl/sql oracle) take first select with top result, then, second.. and so forth... and on each iteration calculate desire goal.

so.. logics is ok with me I think :), but the problem is that I'm not that familiar with PL/SQL, if it had been written in Java it should have come easy to me.

I will pay lots of Thanks to some one who will help me...

its crucial for me to day.

thanks in advance.

---

I have Date and Time is separate columns, like:

```
date            time
----------------------
11-09-2013      12:34
```

so, I made little change like this

```
FOR rec IN
     ( SELECT t.EID, to_char(t.devent_date, 'DD.MM.YY') ||' '|| t.RegTime, t.acttype from turnicate_ie t WHERE t.EID = i_emp_id ORDER BY t.EID
     )
     LOOP
```

but it states that package or function is in incorrect state...

```
(t.devent_date is 11.09.2013, t.RegTime is 16:23)
```

Comment: If it's easier to do in Java, why do you want to do it in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will give you some idea of using plsql:

you need to use many logic of calculating total working hours, like multiple inputs within same time, multiple empId etc.

```
create table my_test ( empId number, log_time date, type varchar2(3));

INSERT INTO my_test VALUES( 1, to_date('11/sep/2013 09:22:00 am', 'dd/mon/yyyy hh:mi:ss am'), 'in');
INSERT INTO my_test VALUES( 1, to_date('11/sep/2013 11:23:00 am', 'dd/mon/yyyy hh:mi:ss am'), 'out');
INSERT INTO my_test VALUES( 1, to_date('11/sep/2013 02:35:00 pm', 'dd/mon/yyyy hh:mi:ss pm'), 'in');
INSERT INTO my_test VALUES( 1, to_date('11/sep/2013 04:21:00 pm', 'dd/mon/yyyy hh:mi:ss pm'), 'out');

CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION total_hours(
          i_emp_id IN NUMBER)
     RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
     l_total_seconds NUMBER := 0;
     in_time         DATE;
     l_total_time VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
     FOR rec IN
     ( SELECT log_time, type FROM my_test WHERE empid = i_emp_id ORDER BY log_time
     )
     LOOP
          IF rec.TYPE   = 'in' AND in_time IS NULL THEN
               in_time := rec.log_time;
          END IF;
          IF rec.TYPE           = 'out' AND in_time IS NOT NULL THEN
               l_total_seconds := (rec.log_time - in_time)*24*60*60 + l_total_seconds;
               in_time         := NULL;
          END IF;
     END LOOP;

     SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(l_total_seconds/3600), 'FM999999990')
          || 'hh '
          || TO_CHAR(TRUNC(mod(l_total_seconds,3600)/60), 'FM00')
          || 'mm '
          || TO_CHAR(mod(l_total_seconds,60), 'FM00')
          ||'ss'
     INTO l_total_time
     FROM dual;
     RETURN l_total_time;
END;
```

/

```
SELECT total_hours(1) from dual;
```

Comment: it says Compilation errors for FUNCTION TURNICATE_USER.TOTAL_HOURS

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
       
          . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
          <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
          like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
       The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.
Line: 23
Text: END IF;